# Realm Facebook Auth V2.0 UnSupported Error

Tags: swift, xcode, mongodb, realm

I am trying to auth via realm facebook,but it gives you me error ;

It looks like unsupported OAuth V2.0 facebook,i did everything that suggested to me

```
Failed to log in to MongoDB Realm: Error Domain=realm::app::ServiceError Code=2 "authentication via 'oauth2-facebook' is unsupported" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=authentication via 'oauth2-facebook' is unsupported, realm::app::ServiceError=InvalidSession}
```

Here my code for login ;

```
  let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn(permissions: [ .email ]) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            let credentials = Credentials.facebook(accessToken: accessToken!.tokenString)
            app.login(credentials: credentials) { result in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Failed to log in to MongoDB Realm: \(error)")
                    case .success(let user):
                        print("Successfully logged in to MongoDB Realm using Facebook OAuth.")
                        // Now logged in, do something with user
                        // Remember to dispatch to main if you are doing anything on the UI thread
                    }
                }
            }
        case .failed(let error):
            print("Facebook login failed: \(error)")
        case .cancelled:
            print("The user cancelled the login flow.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you enable Facebook Authentication in the Realm Console? Also, force-unwrapping optionals can lead to crashes that a hard to track down. Adding a guard statement `accessToken!.tokenString` to accessToken with some error handling would be a good idea,

Comment: i have solved it via,deploy pressing, it was to easy